# pro asp.net example class is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

This is an example in the book pro asp .net but i cannot figure out what goes wrong. I have read many posts with the same questions, but it doesn't solve my issue.

the error says that IProductRepository is inaccessible due to its protection, but I didn't set any thing to private. I dont get it

this is my Product class

```
 namespace SportStore.Domain.Entities
{
    class Product
    {
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
    }
}
```

addbiding method for ninject

```
namespace SportsStore.WebUI.Infrastructure
{
    public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        private IKernel ninjectKernel;
        public NinjectControllerFactory()
        {
            ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel();
            AddBindings();
        }
        protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext
        requestContext, Type controllerType)
        {
            return controllerType == null
            ? null
            : (IController)ninjectKernel.Get(controllerType);
        }

        private void AddBindings()
        {
            Mock<IProductRepository> mock = new Mock<IProductRepository>();
            mock.Setup(m => m.Products).Returns(new List<Product> {
            new Product { Name = "Football", Price = 25 },
            new Product { Name = "Surf board", Price = 179 },
            new Product { Name = "Running shoes", Price = 95 }
            }.AsQueryable());
            ninjectKernel.Bind<IProductRepository>().ToConstant(mock.Object);


        }
    }
}
```

interface

```
namespace SportStore.Domain.Abstract
{
    interface IProductRepository
    {
        IQueryable<Product> Products { get; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the default protection level is `private` unless otherwise specified.  Since the two types are in different namespaces, try setting the interface to `public` (or maybe `internal` if they're in the same assembly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, classes and interfaces are internal to the assembly. Since you are probably working with multiple assemblies, set the interface to public and you should be good to go.